how do I fill missing data that has sector for it's column name and it is divided between Private, Public, and Other
There are missing values the column is called sector and the breakdown is Private, Public and Other. The correlation in the dataset are the Regions where they match the sector according to the region. I need to create a code in Google Collab to fill those missing values and check that the column has been filled once it is completed.
I have checked the missing values which gave me a breakdown of the missing values by inputting a code to give the results.
